# correlated query to update a table based on a select

Tags: sql, many-to-many, subquery

I have these tables `Genre` and `Songs`. There is obviously many to many relationship btw them, as one genre can have (obviously) have many songs and one song may belong to many genre (say there is a song xyz, it belong to rap, it can also belong to hip-hop). I have this table `GenreSongs` which acts as a many to many relationship map btw these two, as it contains `GenreID` and `SongID` column. So, what I am supposed to do this, add a column to this `Genre` table named `SongsCount` which will contain the number of songs in this genre. I can alter table to add a column, also create a query that will give the count of song,

```
SELECT GenreID, Count(SongID) FROM GenreSongs GROUP BY GenreID
```

Now, this gives us what we require, the number of songs per genre, but how can I use this query to update the column I made (`SongsCount`). One way is that run this query and see the results, and then manually update that column, but I am sure everyone will agree that's not a programmtic way to do it.
I came to think I would require to create a query with a subquery, that would get the value of `GenreID` from outer query and then count of its value from inner query (correlated query) but I can't make any. Can any one please help me make this?

Comment: don't forget to accept an answer if it helped you, as a basic courtesy towards others...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question of how to approach this depends on the size of your data and how frequently it is updated.  Here are some scenarios.

If your songs are updated quite frequently and your tables are quite large, then you might want to have a column in Genre with the count, and update the column using a trigger on the Songs table.

Alternatively, you could build an index on the GenreSong table on Genre.  Then the following query:

```
select count(*)
from GenreSong gs
where genre = <whatever>
```

should run quite fast.

If your songs are updated infrequently or in a batch (say nightly or weekly), then you can update the song count as part of the batch.  Your query might look like:

```
update Genre
    set SongCnt = cnt
    from (select Genre, count(*) as cnt from GenreCount gc group by Genre) gc
    where Genre.genre = gc.Genre
```

And yet another possibility is that you don't need to store the value at all.  You can make it part of a view/query that does the calculation on the fly.

Relational databases are quite flexible, and there is often more than one way to do things.  The right approach depends very much on what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

Making a table named SongsCount is just plainly bad design (redundant data and update overhead). Instead use this query for single results:

```
SELECT ID, ..., (SELECT Count(*) FROM GenreSongs WHERE GenreID = X) AS SongsCount FROM Genre WHERE ID = X
```

And this for multiple results (much more efficient):

```
SELECT ID, ..., SongsCount FROM (SELECT GenreID, Count(*) AS SongsCount FROM GenreSongs GROUP BY GenreID) AS sub RIGHT JOIN Genre AS g ON sub.GenreID = g.ID
```